# What is the correct approach to git repository split?

Tags: git

I have a big Git repository that I need to split into 2 repositories - by moving one of the solutions to a new git repository.

**Requirements:**

1. As a part of this process I will need to preserve the history of the solution that I need to move.
2. After I copy/move the solution to new git repo I will have to make some changes that will take weeks (new build pipeline, release pipeline etc) . When I complete the changes I will need to be able to pull all PRs to the solution I worked on that were completed in the original branch from the moment I stated the task.

I read [here](https://medium.com/@ayushya/move-directory-from-one-repository-to-another-preserving-git-history-d210fa049d4b) that it is possible to clone the needed solution and preserve the history. But how can I pull the new pull requests to the solution that were made to the initial git repo from the moment I cloned it?

What is the correct approach in such case?

Comment: I'm afraid cloning the repo and deleting everything from the other solution is the only way to preserve history (though this will be a full history of the whole repository, not history of this particular solution only)

Comment: You might want to read about forking. Try this: https://tharis63.medium.com/git-fork-vs-git-clone-8aad0c0e38c0

Comment: The PRs task is a tough one, surely there's no standard mechanism to resolve it as it's a very rare problem. Perhaps you can clone the repo (no deleting of anything from the other solution and no deleting of git remotes), then configure your solution for two weeks, then pull everything from the old repo again and apply PRs, then delete the other solution and make a new commit, push it to another repo